# can we assign session values to cgridview without dataprovider

Tags: session, yii, shopping-cart, cgridview

Mycart is stored in sessions which I wanna display in cgridview . I have used cgridview with dataprovider but can i do so with session value.Is it possible ?if not what would be the best way out to achieve so .If yes as I have no idea how do i proceed .

Please provide some guidance or examples.Do let me know if I'm not clear I'll make sure to clarify myself.

Comment: use array data provider for gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always create your own HTML table if you don't want to use data provider.

Yii `CGridView` require a data provider, therefore you can't use `CGridView` if you can't supply the data provider. Use `CArrayDataProvider` instead:

```
$sessionData = Yii::app()->user->getState('cart');
// $dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($sessionData);   //throws undefined index:id exception
$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($sessionData, array('keyField'=>'id'));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'your-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => array(
        'item_name',
        'qty',
        // etc
    )
));
```

Comment: thank you works like a wonder but then specify the keyfield else undefined index id exception is thrown i.e., $dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($sessionData,array('keyField'=>'id'));